# Issues with SSL on EC2 behind ELB with nested WordPress blog

Tags: wordpress, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm migrating my website to AWS and have everything up and running on a Linux EC2 instance using ELB to enable SSL/TLS. Everything works fine (codeigniter, phpbb3, osticket) EXCEPT for issues with the WordPress portion of the site which resides in a subdirectory (e.g. www.mysite.com/blog). Portions of the blog are being accessed via http and therefore I am getting a "mixed content" message. I also get infinitely redirected when attempting to log in to the admin portion of the blog.

In order to get https working, I followed Amazon's instructions and added the recommended code to my httpd.conf file.

However, according to this blog (https://blog.lawrencemcdaniel.com/wordpress-aws-elb-ssl), WordPress doesn't work with that.

```
AMAZON RECOMMENDED CODE
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
        RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
    </VirtualHost>
```

I figured there must be a way to apply the rewrite rule to all but one directory so that I can follow the WordPress specific instructions, but I can't seem to find any information on that. (I could just be a poor searcher!). I am open to any help resolving this matter.

----EDIT----

I have since tried the following (neither worked):

1. changed rewrite rule in httpd.conf to

   RewriteRule !^blog https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

and added

```
define('WP_HOME','https://www.example.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.example.com/blog');
```

in wp config file.

2. removed VirtualHost code from httpd.conf file entirely and left WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL in wp config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Here is what ended up working for me.

Use the Amazon recommended code in your httpd.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Add the following to your wp-config.php file

```
define('WP_HOME','https://www.yoursitename.com/yourdirectory');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.yoursitename.com/yourdirectory');
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```